# Read content of file in ksh and split it by ','

Tags: shell-script, shell, ksh

My file.txt contains the following content:-

```
./raw_input/0009/img.raw,./raw_input/0009/calib.raw
```

Answer (score 1):

If your *`ksh`* is `ksh93` or `mksh`, you could read the first line into an array with:

```
IFS=, read -rA array < file.txt
```

Also works in `zsh` or `yash`. For some reason, `bash`, years later, chose to use `-a` instead of `-A` for that.

ksh93 can also do CSV parsing with `-S` (handling quotes and values spanning several lines):

```
IFS=, read -rSA array < file.txt
```

For instance, with a `file.txt` containing:

```
"foo  bar",,"blah""blah
blah"
```

That gives:

```
$ typeset -p array
typeset -a array=('foo  bar' '' $'blah"blah\nblah')
```

To split the *whole file* on commas, you can use split+glob (done implicitly upon unquoted `$(<file)`) with glob disabled:

```
set -o noglob
IFS=,
array=( $(<file.txt) )
```

Or for compatibility with ksh88 / pdksh:

```
set -o noglob
IFS=,
set -A array -- $(<file.txt)
```

Beware `$(<...)` also strips trailing newline characters.

Also note that if the file ends in a `,` (and that also applies with `read` above even with `-S`, except with `zsh`) that doesn't create an extra trailing empty element (`,` is treated as *delimiter*, not *separator*, despite what the `S` in `$IFS` might suggest).

Comment: Thank you, for sharing this!